# What's the meaning of WM_KEYFIRST and WM_KEYDOWN (both 0x0100)? And why it's 4 hex digits long?

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

What's the meaning of

```
#define WM_KEYFIRST 0x0100
#define WM_KEYDOWN  0x0100
#define WM_KEYUP 0x0101
```

? Those are lines 1038, 1039 and 1040 in `winuser.h` library. Why those values and why `WM_KEYFIRST` and `WM_KEYDOWN` both are related to the same value `0x0100`? What's the purpose of making two names to the same value? And why it's 4 hex digits long? Please tell me about this wizardry!

Comment: `WM_KEYFIRST` is probably so you can find the first key really easily or use it in math to get an array index (`arr[key_read - WM_KEYFIRST]`) or for other nefarious purposes.

Comment: About the other question "*why it's 4 hex digits long*", that's because message identifiers used by applications are `WORD` (16-bit) sized. From the [`MSG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msg) documentation: "*message - Type: UINT - The message identifier. Applications can only use the low word; the high word is reserved by the system.*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WM_KEYFIRST` to `WM_KEYLAST` defines the range of keyboard-related messages. This is easier to remember than hardcoding the range to something like `WM_KEYDOWN` to `WM_UNICHAR`, and also more portable, since for example `WM_KEYLAST` was *not* `WM_UNICHAR` before Windows XP.

For an example, the following will filter the keyboard related messages.

```
for(MSG msg; PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE); ) { ... }
```

This is in fact specifically noted in the [`PeekMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew) documentation.

> wMsgFilterMin - Type: UINT - The value of the first message in the range of messages to be examined. Use WM_KEYFIRST (0x0100) to specify the first keyboard message or WM_MOUSEFIRST (0x0200) to specify the first mouse message.
>
> wMsgFilterMax - Type: UINT - The value of the last message in the range of messages to be examined. Use WM_KEYLAST to specify the last keyboard message or WM_MOUSELAST to specify the last mouse message.

Comment: `WM_KEYLAST` value is 0x0109, and `WM_MOUSELAST` value is 0x0209. I read it from [WineHQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages) but have found no official definition for it, so take it with a grain of salt. I needed the value, because I was not working with C/C++, and couldn't rely on *.h files.

Comment: @AdamL.S. The authoritative source is the official Windows SDK, where these constants are #define'd in `winuser.h`. For a tidbit of ancient history related to `WM_KEYLAST` see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977562/windows-message-identifier-0x0108-wm-yomichar).

Comment: Technical true, but don't know where Visual Studio installs the header file (for me to read it). That is why I turn to MS Docs, which I did not find at the time. Thanks for the link btw.