# Windows message identifier 0x0108 (WM_YOMICHAR)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

While answering an unrelated `WM_KEYLAST` question, I noticed the following gap in `winuser.h`.

```
#define WM_SYSDEADCHAR                  0x0107
#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
#define WM_UNICHAR                      0x0109
#define WM_KEYLAST                      0x0109
#else
#define WM_KEYLAST                      0x0108
#endif /* _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501 */
```

For versions prior to XP, the last keyboard message listed is `WM_SYSDEADCHAR` defined as `0x0107`, but `WM_KEYLAST` is defined to be one higher than that, as `0x0108`.

This goes back to the early 16-bit SDKs, and suggests that there existed another keyboard message with identifier `0x0108`. The value remained reserved in all Windows versions to date.

A cursory 'net search found little about it, though one page had this reference.

```
#define WM_YOMICHAR             0x0108      /* ;Internal JAPAN */
```

I was wondering if anyone saw this before, and has some background on "*message* *`0x0108`*".

Comment: After confirming with the relevant developer, The `WM_YOMICHAR` is an internal message and is undocumented.

Comment: Thank you @DrakeWu-MSFT, I appreciate. Guess it's not the only undocumented message, but what makes this one a bit different is that it's part of the documented range `WM_KEYFIRST` to `WM_KEYLAST`.

Comment: This is a snippet from Borland C 5.02 (from year 1997) win16\windows.h:

`#define WM_SYSCHAR          0x0106
#define WM_SYSDEADCHAR      0x0107


/* Keyboard message range */
#define WM_KEYFIRST         0x0100
#define WM_KEYLAST          0x0108`

There is no such message, but same distribution OWL\eventhan.cpp:
`    { 0x0107, "WM_SYSDEADCHAR"           },
    { 0x0108, "wm_yomichar"              },`
has one. wm_yomichar string is also found in bcwdbgv.dll

Try to install turbo c for windows 3.1 and search there.

Comment: Thank you @nevilad, forgot to check venerable Borland. Going even farther back, I found what must be among the first references in Microsoft's Windows 3.1 DDK from 1992 `286\inc\windows.h` (`#define WM_YOMICHAR 0x0108 /* JAPAN */ /* ;Internal */`) and `386\include\windows.inc` (`WM_YOMICHAR = 0108h ;Internal`).